# With Quartz in Cocoa OSX and iOS, how do you draw lines and "connect" shapes?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, draw, shapes, quartz-2d

Using Objective C and some mix of Cocoa and Quartz, is it possible to build something like Visio? Specifically to:

1. draw a line from one object to another object,
2. have it connect and "lock on" to the second object, with a colored square to arrow at either end of the line, and
3. have the line stay connected if you drag the objects.

Answer (score 3):

you want `NSBezierPath` on OSX and `UIBezierPath` on iOS. using OSX as an example, to draw a line from A to B (where A & B are NSPoints) in an NSView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
  NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
  [path moveToPoint:A];
  [path lineToPoint:B];
  [path stroke];
}
```

if you wanted to draw a box represented by an NSRect r, you would do:

```
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:r];
[path stroke];
```

etc. there's loads of stuff you can do.

as far as tracking the connections, that's something you have to handle yourself (i.e. not something provided by OSX/iOS).

Comment: Thank you, just tried it out and you gave me some ideas. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for OSX && swift 4.x (tested on Xcode 9.1)

```
//  CustomView.swift
//  cocoaCustomDraw
//
//  Created by ing.conti on 1/28/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 ing.conti. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class CustomView: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.

        // https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

        guard let aContext = NSGraphicsContext.current else{
            return
        }

        // eventually..
        aContext.saveGraphicsState()

        // Set the drawing attributes

        // Draw the object
        NSColor.blue.set()
        NSColor.yellow.setFill()

        // https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html

        let aPath = NSBezierPath()
        aPath.move(to: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        aPath.line(to: NSPoint(x: 100, y: 100))

        aPath.curve(to: NSPoint(x:180, y: 210),
        controlPoint1: NSPoint(x: 60, y: 20),
        controlPoint2: NSPoint(x: 280, y: 100))

        //aPath.appendRect( NSRect(x: 2.0, y: 16.0, width:  8.0,  height: 5.0))

        aPath.close()

        aPath.fill()
        aPath.stroke()


        // eventually..
        aContext.restoreGraphicsState()
    }   
}
```

You will get:

[image]